# How to convert a string into object variable in ObjectiveC (iOS)

Tags: ios, string, object, eval

I am asking myself how can I convert string value into an object variable in Objective C - iOS. I know that in JavaScript you can do this with eval() function.

I want something like that:

```
NSString *variableString = @"variable";
NSNumber *myVariable = myObject.{variableString};
```

It this possible in ObjectiveC ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Key Value Coding, KVC.

```
NSString *string = [myInstance valueForKey:@"stringProperty"];
```

Comment: And I thought that KVC only works with array and dictionaries. Thanks man!

Comment: Do you know how can I retrieve myInstance object instead of his value? I need this cos I need to check which data type is conforming object... ?

Answer (score -2):

If I understand correctly what you mean by an object variable, you are looking for objective-c's id. See this blogpost for a great explanation of id: http://unixjunkie.blogspot.com/2008/03/id-vs-nsobject-vs-id.html.